# My textView bottomAnchor does not seem to work?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, swift4

I have a textView and I have a line, I set the line's frame without contraints and set textView frame with constraints. Simply what I want is the textView to follow the line, so I put a bottomAnchor to textView equal to the topAnchor of the line. Yet when I animate the line the textView does not follow? What am I doing wrong?

```
    var button = UIButton()
    var testLine = UIView()
    let textView = UITextView()
    var textViewBottomAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testLine.backgroundColor = .black
        testLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 335, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 10)
        view.addSubview(testLine)

        view.addSubview(textView)


        textView.frame = .zero//CGRect(x: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 16), y: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 300), width: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 282), height: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 35))
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        textView.text = ""
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 15)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isHidden = false

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLine.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        textViewBottomAnchorConstraint = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLine.topAnchor, constant: 0)
        textViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

            self.testLine.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 30)

        }) { (true) in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Vollan correctly said animating `transform` property is not the best option. Here is quote from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform): "In iOS 8.0 and later, **the transform property does not affect Auto Layout**. Auto layout calculates a view’s alignment rectangle based on its untransformed frame." Therefore animation of `transform` property doesn't change layout of `textView`. I recommend you to animate `frame` property instead of `transform`.

However, if you switch to `frame` animation it doesn't fix all your problems. If you keep your animation inside `viewDidLoad` method you may encounter very strange behavior. The reason is that in `viewDidLoad` the view itself is not yet laid out properly. Starting animation inside `viewDidLoad` may lead to unpredicted results.

At last you need adjust your animation block. Apple recommends to apply `layoutIfNeeded` **inside** the animation block. Or at least they used to recommend it then autolayout was introduced - watch [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/228/) (starting from 30th minute) for further details.

If you apply all recommendations above your code should look like this:

```
    var button = UIButton()
    var testLine = UIView()
    let textView = UITextView()
    var textViewBottomAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var triggeredAnimation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testLine.backgroundColor = .black
        testLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 335, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 10)
        view.addSubview(testLine)

        view.addSubview(textView)


        textView.frame = .zero//CGRect(x: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 16), y: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 300), width: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 282), height: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 35))
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        textView.text = ""
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 15)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isHidden = false

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLine.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        textViewBottomAnchorConstraint = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLine.topAnchor, constant: 0)
        textViewBottomAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // viewDidAppear may be called several times during view controller lifecycle
        // triggeredAnimation ensures that animation will be called just once
        if self.triggeredAnimation {
            return
        }
        self.triggeredAnimation = true

        let oldFrame = self.testLine.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.testLine.frame = CGRect(x: oldFrame.minX, y: oldFrame.minY + 30, width: oldFrame.width,
                                         height: oldFrame.height)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor points make references to others positions, meaning. It is still referensed to `y = 355` as you transform it and not actually "move" it.

What i recommend is that you don't mix using frame-based layout and anchorpoints / layout constraints.